# codeigniter s3 image upload works locally but not on production

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I have a model called **photos_model.php** which does the backend work to upload images to s3

here is the function that uploads to s3

```
public function uploadPhoto($photo){
    $this->load->model("misc_model");

    //required vars
    $tmp_name = $photo["tmp_name"];
    $name = $photo["name"];
    $type = $photo["type"];
    $size = $photo["size"];
    $error_upload = $photo["error"];


    $random_str = $this->misc_model->generateRandomNumber(20, true, true);

    $this->s3->putBucket($this->config->item("bucket"), S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

    if($this->s3->putObjectFile($tmp_name, $this->config->item("bucket") , 'photos/'.$random_str.".jpg", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) ){
        echo 'ok';
    }else{
        echo 'fail';
    }

}
```

**the s3 library:**

taken from here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease/

this will work on my local machine MAC OS X Lion

but when i try the script on an **amazon ec2 machine** it simply doesnt print anything... like nothing...

Comment: have you check cURL extension enabled on amazon ec2 instance ?

Comment: i just run `sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl` , restarted apache2 but still nothing

Comment: ok. can you check error_log ?

Comment: its always the error_log... it was reporting `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()` so i installed GD library and we're good... now gotta fix some other problems... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

its always the error_log... it was reporting `PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()` so i installed GD library and we're good